# Writing jasmine tests based on state.params

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

My controller looks like below:

```
function Ctrl1($scope,$state, $modal, $q, ResourceABC) {

  function1(){ /*..   something happens here.*/}
  function2(){ /*.. something happens here .*/}
  function3(){ /*.. something happens here.*/}

if (!$state.params.gameID) {
    var singleGameID = 'tmp-xyz';
    var multipleGameID = 'gen-abc';    

    if ($state.current.name === 'single-user') {
      $scope.player.gameID = singleGameID;
    }    
    else if ($state.current.name === 'multi-user') {
      $scope.player.gameID = multipleGameID;
    }    
    else {
      $scope.player.gameID = singleGameID;
    }

  }
  else {
    $scope.player.gameID = $state.params.gameID;
}

}
```

I wrote code to test the same which is as below:

```
describe('Ctrl1',function(){

  var $rootScope,$controller,$httpBackend,q,state;

  beforeEach(module(game));

  beforeEach(function(){

    angular.mock.inject(function($injector){
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $controller = $injector.get('$controller');      
      q = $injector.get('$q');
      state = $injector.get('$state');
    });

    var scope = $rootScope.$new();
    var resource1 = sinon.stub({});

    createController = function(){
      return $controller('DynamicRegistrationDialogCtrl',{
        $scope: scope,
        $state: state,        
        $q: q,
        ResourceABC: resource1       
      });
    }

  });

  it('should check that $scope.player.gameID is set',function(){

  });

});
```

My question is :

1. when i just want to test a small functionality fo the controller, do i have to load all the dependency while create the $controller in the test  ?
2. Secondly, how do I test that $scope.player.gameID is set ? I mean how do i pass in $state.parmams.
   what is the couse of action here ?